# sqlalchemy: non-trivial one-to-one relationship with multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm struggling with creating a database model for my Flask application.

Let's consider I have few product types and due to nature of my application I want to have separate tables for each product, while keeping generic properties in a common table:

[image: Database diagram]

Example:

- *products* table

  ```
  id  type          name      price
  1   'motorcycle'  'Harley'  10000.00
  2   'book'        'Bible'   9.99
  ```
- *motorcycles* table

  ```
  id  manufacturer       model                max_speed
  1   'Harley-Davidson'  'Night Rod Special'  150
  ```
- *books* table

  ```
  id  author              pages
  2   'Some random dude'  666
  ```

Things to consider:

- all tables have one-to-one relationship
- having *motorcycle_id*, *book_id*, *etc_id* in *products* table is **not** an option
- having *product_id* in product tables is acceptable
- two-way relationship

How can I declare such a relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).  The base class and each subclass each create their own table, each subclass has a foreign key primary key pointing to the base table.  SQLAlchemy will automatically handle the joining whether you query the base or sub class.

Here is a working example for some products:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Numeric
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    price = Column(Numeric(7, 2), nullable=False, default=Decimal(0.0))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,  # subclasses will each have a unique type
    }


class Motorcycle(Product):
    __tablename__ = 'motorcycle'

    # id is still primary key, but also foreign key to base class
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Product.id), primary_key=True)
    manufacturer = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    model = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    max_speed = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'motorcycle',  # unique type for subclass
    }


class Book(Product):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Product.id), primary_key=True)
    author = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    pages = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'book',
    }


Base.metadata.create_all()

# insert some products
session.add(Book())
session.add(Motorcycle())
session.commit()

print(session.query(Product).count())  # 2 products
print(session.query(Book).count())  # 1 book
```